# MassTransit integration with SaasKit: How to generate the tenant when consuming messages?

Tags: multi-tenant, masstransit, saaskit

I'm integrating MassTransit on a solution that uses SaasKit to implement multi-tenancy.

My DbContext uses the method of defining the connection string in "OnConfiguring" as described here:

https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-multi-tenancy-data-isolation-with-entity-framework

The problem is that when consuming messages, the Tenant does not exists, so the DbContext is not properly initialized.

How do I inject the Tenant inside the lifecycle of MassTransit?

I'm using AspNet Core dependency injection, where I add the tenant like this:

```
public void Configure(...)
(...)
app.UseMultitenancy<MyTenant>();
```

Bus configuration:

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
(...)
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "customer-updated", ep =>
                {
                    ep.PrefetchCount = 1;
                    ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));

                    ep.ConfigureConsumer<CustomerUpdatedConsumer>(provider);
                    EndpointConvention.Map<ICustomerUpdated>(ep.InputAddress);
                });
```

Inside my DbContext constructor, only when consuming messages, I keep getting MyTenant as null ...

```
 public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, MyTenant tenant)
        {
            this.tenant = tenant;
        }
```

Does anyone already tried to integrate SaasKit with MassTransit?

Thanks

Comment: SaasKit seems pretty ancient by open-source standards, not sure how it works and it hasn't been updated in years.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson you're right, I will try to create my own tenant context. One more question. To add/read tenant context from the message (im thinking of using the message headers), should I use the observers? I need to inject the headers on publish (publish observer) and recreate the context on consume (consume observer).

Comment: Write a middleware filter to do it, which is called on every send and every consume, that way it's prior to consumers executing.